# How to use the same component in more than one place in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, reference, duplicates, components, fxml

I want to use the same `MenuItem` in a `MenuBar` and in a `ContextMenu` (both have the same text, will be enabled/diSabled under the same conditions, and will perform the same task). How can I achieve this in FXML in the same file?

I tried using `<fx:reference>` but it only shows up in the first place I deference it.

```
    <MenuBar>
        <menus>
             <MenuItem fx:id="menuToDuplicate" />
        </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    .
    .
    .
    <ContextMenu>
        <items>
             <!--Same MenuItem as above -->
        </items>
    </ContextMenu>
```

Comment: I can't find documentation on this (unlike `Node`), but I doubt you could use the _same_ `MenuItem` reference in more than one location—especially since it has properties such as `parentMenu` and `parentPopup`. That said, you could _try_ [`fx:reference`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#reference_elements). But again, I don't believe this is possible. Also, a `MenuItem` eventually gets "mapped" to a `Node`, which explicitly can only appear once in the scene graph.

Comment: In short, you cannot. Like a `Node`, a `MenuItem` instance may only appear in a scene once at a time. You can, however, create two `MenuItem` objects that are configured the same way (calling the same `onAction()` method, for example).

Comment: To rephrase in another way, it's impossible for a person to appear at two different places at the same time. If you are sighted somewhere else at the same time, it means you have an identical twin, or someone has done some terrible biological experiment on you called "cloning."

Comment: @Jai - that explanation makes it sound like identical twins are a bad thing, or that they shouldn't/can't exist... And cloning is perfectly acceptable in Java; it is, after all, one of the basic features of OOP. If a class definition is the DNA, then every object instantiated from that class **is** a clone. Either way, whether a twin or a clone, it doesn't explain why the OP's method is wrong, frowned-upon, or invalid (which it is).

Answer (score 0):

Menu and ContexMenu both have MenuItems (an ObservableList). So the same items can be used by a Menu and a ContextMenu. If you create the menus programmatically, honouring the DRY principle is possible for sure.

```
Menu menu = new Menu("Album List");
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Refresh");
item.setOnAction(e -> refresh());

// add the same menu item to both the menu and the contextmenu
menu.getItems().add(item)
contextMenu.getItems().add(item)
```